# How can I Ignore the first paragraph but affect all the others in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

While using selectors, how can we ignore the first element and then effect all of the remaining elements in that selector?

For example:

```
<p>Users said:</p>
<p>Hey Ya!</p>
<p>Hey Ya 2!</p>
<p>Hey Ya 3..!</p>
```

Now I want to ignore the first one that says `Users said:`, and affect all the other  `<p>`s. I took a look at `:gt` selector but it doesn't help. Are there any alternatives for `:gt` or any other way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I took a look at `:gt` selector but it doesn't help." Are you sure you're looking for a CSS selector? Because that's not a CSS selector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
p:not(:first-child) {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

note that this works only on css3

---

if you have an older browser you should do something like this

```
p {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
p:first-child {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

you basicly need to revert your changes that you made for the first element

Comment: Specifically, [`:not()` isn't supported in IE 8 and earlier, Safari 1.2 and earlier, and Opera 9 and earlier](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%3Anot%28%29).

Comment: if you are dealing with old browsers, you can always target all the p tags, then set :first-child to default